# What to do when you cannot position your image correctly in html?

Tags: html, css

The css code below was written by me when trying to create a fixed header like mashable.com,but however hard i try i cannot seem to make the logo.png to appear with margin:auto 19px;.Pleae help me and tell me what im doing wrong.I am a beginner to html and css,so please be gentle. And I want the logo and the nav list to be in a single line.

```
header{position:fixed;
   background:#333;
   height:128px;}

h1{    display:inline;
       float:left;
   background:url(images/logo.png) no-repeat;
       width:289px;height:47px;
       margin:
       text-indent:-9999px;}

nav {   

         height:26px;
         float:right;
     margin-top:19px;
     width:631px;}

nav ul li{
          display:inline;}
```

This is the html:

```
<header>
    <h1>logo</h1>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Categories</li>
            <li>Search</li>
            <li>About me</li>
            <li>Contact me</li>                 
            <li>Social</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Create a Fiddle with your code - **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)**

Comment: Can you show the html?

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/7Q6m2/

Comment: You are missing something in your code.. on line with h1 margin: without value and ;? But I think u just withdraw it from the code to text instead of copy.

Comment: I recommend you take a look at this website: [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/). They have a lot of awesome tutorials. Also, make sure you stick with a consistent indenting style. [Tutorial on CSS Formatting](http://css-tricks.com/different-ways-to-format-css/). It is not good practice to have code indented the way you do. Also, where is the image you want to format?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/edYcR/ this will work

Comment: @mrd You should remove any unnecessary styles from that fiddle. (i.e. the background)

Comment: @screenmutt Just there to highlight the fact the header is fixed.

Comment: If the h1 tag is just an image of the logo, why are you using a h1 over an img?

Comment: @MrD I just read somewhere that it was good for seo purposes.

Comment: @AnanthakrishnanVellaparambil use an img and just define the alt attribute

Answer (score 0):

Margin auto only works on block elements, not inline ones.  If you want the logo to be centred then change 2 things in the h1 css:

1. Change to `display: block;`
2. Remove `float: left;`

Obviously add the margin value too but i'm assuming that is just a copy/paste typo.

Comment: But I want the image to be in line with the nav list.